# How to use mixin block into inline javascript?

Tags: pug

I have this pug template code

```
mixin predicciontxt
  h2 #[+entrada] .
  | #[+hoy] .
  | \r\n .
```

How can I use "predicciontxt" into inline javascript code, like this

```
mixin predicciontxt
  h2 #[+entrada] .
  | #[+hoy] .
  | \r\n . 
- console.log(#[predicciontxt])
```

Thanks

Comment: You're trying to pass the rendered html block into javascript as a string? On the client side or on the server?

Comment: @Sean I'm running on the server side using node cli

Comment: What do you want to log to the console—the text content of the mixin, the pug code, or the rendered html?

Comment: @Sean the final content of the mixin

Comment: If you're using gulp or some other process to save the rendered html on the server, you could write a process that then consumes the output file as HTML. But you would need to do this in node, and it wouldn't be possible from within a Pug file.

Answer (score 3):

Mixins are processed during the template render, so by the time node.js gets there you won't be able to access the content.

The usage paradigm for pug is to process/transform your data in the route handler and then pass that on to the template for conversion into HTML.  What you are trying to do is the opposite - process HTML in the template and then pass it back to the route handler.

To summarize, what you're trying to do isn't possible and is not how pug was designed to work.